# How do you use a converter to enable/disable a Xaml control in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, binding, viewmodel

As a starting point, my test project is a Xamarin Forms Tab project - from the Xamarin templates.

I have a converter:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace TabExample.Converters
{
    public class HaveItemsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null && value is ICollection)
            {
                return ((ICollection)value).Count > 0;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

I have added it to App.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:TabExample.Converters"
             x:Class="TabExample.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <!-- Converters -->
            <converters:HaveItemsConverter x:Key="HaveItemsConverter"/>

            <!--Global Styles-->
            <Color x:Key="NavigationPrimary">#2196F3</Color>
            <Style TargetType="NavigationPage">
                <Setter Property="BarBackgroundColor" Value="{StaticResource NavigationPrimary}" />
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="White" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I've updated the ListView in ItemsPage.xml to add IsEnabled, using the converter.

```
        <ListView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             HasUnevenRows="true"
             RefreshCommand="{Binding LoadItemsCommand}"
             IsPullToRefreshEnabled="true"
             IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=OneWay}"
             CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
             ItemSelected="OnItemSelected"
             IsEnabled="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HaveItemsConverter}, Source={x:Reference BrowseItemsPage}}">
```

In ItemsPage.xaml.cs I added ItemsProperty:

```
    public List<Item> Items
    {
        get { return (List<Item>)GetValue(ItemsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ItemsProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly BindableProperty ItemsProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("Items", typeof(List<Item>), typeof(ItemsPage), null, BindingMode.OneWay);
```

This does not work.  The converter receives null.  What I need is the converter to use the Items ObservableCollection from the ItemsViewModel:

```
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; set; }
```

How do I property hook up binding in the Xaml to use the HaveItemsConverter to retrieve the list from ItemsViewModel and return a bool that is used to enable or disable the list?

Comment: Why are you adding `, Source={x:Reference BrowseItemsPage}` at the end? It doesn't look like you need it, as you are binding the property `Items` directly just a few lines above.

Comment: I don't know what I need for the binding, that's the question.  What I really need is to bind to the list in the ViewModel - in this case it is the ObservableCollection<Item> Items, not a list in the view.

Comment: Are the items are being displayed in the `ListView` when you remove the `IsEnabled` property? If so, `{Binding Items}` is working fine, which means that doing `IsEnabled="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HaveItemsConverter}}"` should probably work.

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:**

```
Source={x:Reference BrowseItemsPage}
```

When you set the Source , the `BindingContext` will be changed at same time;

**Solution:**

What is the `BrowseItemsPage`? If it is your viewmodel , you should set the **BindingContext** in contentPage .Otherwise just use

```
IsEnabled="{Binding Items, Mode=OneWay , Converter={StaticResource HaveItemsConverter}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't get the full scope your code, that is why I am providing the Simple and quick solution, add one more property like ItemsAvailable,

```
bool _itemsAvailable;
Public bool ItemsAvailable 
{get {return _itemsAvailable;}}
{set {_itemsAvailable=value; RaisePropert....}}
```

And set the above bool variable under your Observablecollection **Set** like below,

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> _items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return _items;
        }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            if(_items!=null && _items.Count>0)
            {
                ItemsAvailable = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

And bind this ItemsAvailable property for your Visible Property and remove converter which is not required.
Happy coding :)